# Case Statement with duplicate values, Hadoop

Tags: sql, hive, hue, case-statement

I am working with email addresses who have signed up once with zero value and then again with certain amount attached. I can do a distinct email query with case statement but what I am struggling with is, if an email has zero value in gross amount, then search for that email in rest of the table with >0 value and give that email address as distinct.

Any suggestions?

Sample Data:
Table with two field - Email and Gross Amount

```
Email: abc@gmail.com | Gross Amt: $0    
Email: abc@gmail.com | Gross Amt: $50    
Email: xyz@gmail.com | Gross Amt: $0
```

Output needed:

```
Email with 0 value: xyz@gmail.com    
Email with >0 value: abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output in table format

Answer (score 1):

Try below - using aggregation and group by

```
select email, sum(amount)
from tablename
group by email
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to gather what % of emails have amount attached out of all or total emails. Aggregate of amount is not required, rather no. of emails with >0 value out of total.

Comment: but in that case your xyz@gmail.com will be discarded @Rashltls

Comment: @RashItIs this query result your expected output. So the expected output you post is wrong, and you should update your question with your real expected output, and logic to get it.

Comment: @RashItIs . . . You should ask *another* question with the percentage that you seem to want.  This question has nothing about that and already has many answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select email,
sum(case when t1.GrossAmt=0 then 1 end) total
sum(case when t1.GrossAmt> then GrossAmt end) 
from table_name 
group by email
```

Comment: But that same email may also have >0 value in the table and in that case, only 0 will not suffice.

Comment: @RashItIs not much clear about your requirement but it seems me you want total 0 amount email count and sum of amount i

Answer (score 0):

That’s the challenge. The email with 0 value only once is required, but if it has more than two values & one is 0, then discard 0 & consider value >0.

May be creating two tables, one with 0s and one with >0s, and then joining on email  address work? Pick email & gross amount1 from table1, if gross amount1=0 from table1, then pick gross amount=2 from table2?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using row_number() as well.

```
select email, grossamt from (select email, grossamt, row_number() over (partition email order by grossamt desc) as rnk from table) A where a.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can it this using analytic functions. Please read comments in the query:

```
select case when emailGrossAmt=0 then 'Email with 0 value'  
             when emailGrossAmt>0 then 'Email with > 0 value' 
          end as grp, 
        email, 
        GrossAMT
from
(
select  s.*,
        case when emailGrossAmt=0 then row_number() over(partition by email) else 1 end zero_rn --we need only one record with zeroAMT
from        
(
select email, GrossAMT, 
       sum(GrossAmt) over(partition by email) emailGrossAmt,
       dense_rank() over(partition by email order by case when GrossAmt=0 then 1 else 0 end)  rnk   --to pass all >0, they will have rnk=1       
from
( --replace this subquery(s) with your table
select stack(5,
'abc@gmail.com',0  ,
'abc@gmail.com',50 ,
'abc@gmail.com',500 ,
'xyz@gmail.com',0,
'xyz@gmail.com',0 ) as (email, GrossAMT)
) s --your table
) s 
where rnk=1
)s where zero_rn=1
```

Result:

```
Email with > 0 value    abc@gmail.com   500
Email with > 0 value    abc@gmail.com   50
Email with 0 value      xyz@gmail.com   0
```

All rows with emailGrossAmt>0 are returned except records with 0 amount.
Only one record per email with emailGrossAmt=0 returned

Maybe it still can be optimized, but hope, you got the idea